# 'HttpClientHandler' does not contain a definition for 'ServerCertificateValidationCallback' .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard

I am currently in the process of migrating a huge solution from .Net Framework 4.7.2 to .Net Core 3.1. In the current Project (which now targets .Net Standard 2.0) we had the following code (already changed from WebRequestHandler):

```
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = proxy,
            UseDefaultCredentials = useDefaultCredentials,
        };

        if (Configuration.TrustCertificate)
        {
            handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate
            {
                return true;
            };
        }
```

After the migration to .Net Standard 2.0 I get the following build error:

> CS1061 'HttpClientHandler' does not contain a definition for 'ServerCertificateValidationCallback' and no accessible extension method 'ServerCertificateValidationCallback' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpClientHandler' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have referenced the nuget package System.Net.Http (v4.3.4). When I view the definition I see that the ServerCertificateValidationCallback is there but marked as `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`
The header of the file is also suspicious:

```
#region Assembly netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
// C:\Users\myuser\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\netstandard.dll
#endregion
```

I would have expected that the class was in the System.Net.Http package.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the property is [`ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback?view=net-6.0#system-net-http-httpclienthandler-servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback). If you change the property name, the build error should be fixed.